# How to make a vbs spam bot?

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to make a spam bot, the basic function works fine but the counter isn't. It should go from and imputed number [i] and stop at another [count] and if count < i; it should count backwards. But it is not stopping at count, it keeps going, It won't count backwards either.

```
    set shl = createobject("wscript.shell")
    spam = inputbox("What do you want to spam?")
    if spam = "/count" then
        i = inputbox("Start at what number?")
        count = inputbox("Stop at what number?")
        wscript.sleep 2500

        if count > i then
            do while count > i
                shl.sendkeys i
                wscript.sleep 10
                shl.sendkeys "{ENTER}"
            wscript.sleep 10
            i = i + 1
            loop

         elseif count < i then
            do while count < i
                shl.sendkeys i
                wscript.sleep 10
                shl.sendkeys "{ENTER}"
                wscript.sleep 10
                i = i - 1
            loop

         else
            shl.sendkeys i
        end if

     end if
else
    count = inputbox("How many times?")
    wscript.sleep 2500
    do while count > 0
        shl.sendkeys spam
        wscript.sleep 10
        shl.sendkeys "{ENTER}"
        wscript.sleep 10
        count = count - 1
    loop
end if
```

I'm also going to make a function where you can send multiple lines. Any other ideas?

Comment: Spam bots are basically malware, and I would ask everyone to not assist in the creation of these things.

Comment: Ya I agree with that, but I need projects and I rarely put these into use.

PS. I have never and will never use it on someone other than joking with a friend.

Answer (score 2):

```
set shell = createobject ("wscript.shell")

strtext = inputbox ("Write down your message you like to spam")
strtext2 = inputbox ("Message 2")
strtext3 = inputbox ("Message 3")
strtext4 = inputbox ("Message 4")
strtext5 = inputbox ("Message 5")
strtimes = inputbox ("How many times do you like to spam? Type in 1 less than the amount of msgs you want to spam. eg; if want to spam 1000, type 999.Max no.1999")
strspeed = inputbox ("Type 1000 for 1 msg per second 100 for 10 msg per second etc type 1 for fastest")
strtimeneed = inputbox ("How many SECONDS do you need to get to your victims input box? Click where you want to spam.")
If not isnumeric (strtimes & strspeed & strtimeneed) then
msgbox "You entered something else then a number on Times, Speed and/or Time need. shutting down"
wscript.quit
End If
strtimeneed2 = strtimeneed * 1000
do
msgbox "You have " & strtimeneed & " seconds to get to your input area where you are going to spam."
wscript.sleep strtimeneed2
for i=0 to strtimes
shell.sendkeys (strtext & "{enter}")
shell.sendkeys (strtext2 & "{enter}")
shell.sendkeys (strtext3 & "{enter}")
shell.sendkeys (strtext4 & "{enter}")
shell.sendkeys (strtext5 & "{enter}")
wscript.sleep strspeed
Next
wscript.sleep strspeed * strtimes / 10

returnvalue=MsgBox ("Want to spam again?",36)
If returnvalue=6 Then
End If
If returnvalue=7 Then
msgbox "Spambox is shutting down"
wscript.quit
End IF
strtext = inputbox ("Write down your message you like to spam")
strtimes = inputbox ("How many times do you like to spam? Type in 1 less than the amount of msgs you want to spam. eg; if want to spam 1000, type 999")
strspeed = inputbox ("Type 1000 for 1 msg per second 100 for 10 msg per second etc type 1 for fastest")
strtimeneed = inputbox ("How many SECONDS do you need to get to your victims input box? Click where you want to spam")
loop
```

This is my edit of a code I found online that allows for multiple lines

Answer (score 0):

I think on the countdown you put     `else if`, instead of     `Elseif`, i have also changed some of the indentation to make it easier to read